# Facing Problem with libxml.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded one of the rails app from server and tried running it. I faced an error on migration

```
D:\Radiant\trunk>rake db:migrate
(in D:/Radiant/trunk)
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - D:/Radiant/trunk/config/../ven
dor/plugins/libxml-ruby/lib/libxml_ruby.so
```

I got the windows version of libxml_ruby. I tried again.

I got the error saying "libxml2.dll" not found. Then i checked the file libxml.rb. It says the below lines .

```
# If running on Windows, then add the current directory to the PATH
# for the current process so it can find the pre-built libxml2 and 
# iconv2 shared libraries (dlls).
```

Can anybody explain me what actually this mean?

Regards
Rakesh S

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully installed libxml-ruby gem on yours windows, search for libxml2.dll on the system. You will find it in gem folder. Copy this file and save it in `<ruby_install_dir>\bin`.